# JSOUP malformed error when trying to get visited sites

Tags: java, eclipse, jsoup

I'm trying to get a list of links and form those list of links I want to get the ones that are visited from an specific website using JSOUP.

Currently I'm trying to do it from here.

```
    public void doCrawl(String url){
    Set<String> thisPageLinks = getLinks(url);
    pageVisited.add(url);

    for (String link: thisPageLinks){
        if (link.contains(this.domain) && !pageVisited.contains(link) && !link.contains("#")){
            logger.info("Subcrawling {}", link);

            doCrawl(link);
        } 
    }
    this.pageLinks.addAll(thisPageLinks);
}

// Obiene los links en un URL dado
public Set<String> getLinks(String url){
    Set<String> links = new HashSet<String>();


    try {

        // 1. Obtiene los links de un URL específico y regresa el
        // set de strings
        // escribe aquí tu código {


        Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(this.USER_AGENT).execute();

        Document doc = res.parse();

        Elements elements = doc.select("a");


        for(Element element: elements){

              links.add(element.attr("href"));

        }

        // }
        return links;



    } catch(IOException io){
        logger.error(io);
        System.err.println(io.getMessage());
        io.printStackTrace();
        return links;
    }
}
```

With this I'm getting all the links from the website or link given, that part works, but when I try to validate the ones visited from the method doCrawl() I get this errors

```
https://stackoverflow.com
Terminando programa.Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed URL: //pt.stackoverflow.com
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:78)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:38)
at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73)
at web.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:78)
at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:53)
at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:60)
at web.Crawler.crawl(Crawler.java:48)
at web.MainCrawler.main(MainCrawler.java:29)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: //pt.stackoverflow.com
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:593)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:76)
... 7 more
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE: I change to absolute href's and seems like is working but this time I get this error. Is probable because the document I'm connecting to doesn't have html content?

```
Unhandled content type. Must be text/*, application/xml, or  application/xhtml+xml
org.jsoup.UnsupportedMimeTypeException: Unhandled content type. Must be text/*, application/xml, or application/xhtml+xml. Mimetype=application/zip, URL=https://codeload.github.com/gist/c1f5e6ae5208f0b2f83713eaa175d409/zip/master
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:547)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:534)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
    at web.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:78)
    at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:53)
    at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:60)
    at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:60)
    at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:60)
    at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:60)
    at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:60)
    at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:60)
    at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:60)
    at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:60)
    at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:60)
    at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:60)
    at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:60)
    at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:60)
    at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:60)
    at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:60)
    at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:60)
    at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:60)
    at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:60)
    at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:60)
    at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:60)
    at web.Crawler.doCrawl(Crawler.java:60)
    at web.Crawler.crawl(Crawler.java:48)
    at web.MainCrawler.main(MainCrawler.java:29)
```

Comment: Try using absolute urls. Compare https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls

Comment: Just did and update it. Thank you!

Comment: Your guess regarding the new error is correct, since you are trying to download a zip file there, which can't be parsed by jsoup, so you need to improve your error handling/type checking.